# Menu Table not rendering correctly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix the menu table so it is consistent with the homepage but with no luck. The main index.php page uses its own css for some reason.

[lcrisq.com](http://lcrisq.com)

[image]

What it should look like:

[image]

Here is the style.css:

```
.chromestyle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 33px;
    margin-left: 195px;
    width: 401px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.chromestyle ul{
    background: url('images/backgrounds/nav.png') repeat-x top left;
    width: 431px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.chromestyle td{
    background: url('images/backgrounds/nav.png') repeat-x top left;
    width: 131px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: -30px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Looks like what I need to do is decrease the td some how
[image]

Comment: use !important to override its css.

Comment: Your home page has an image slider. The others don't. How do you expect them to look similar?

Comment: Either way I need to make the other menu bar thats not on the homepage shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#container > table td:nth-child(2) {text-align: right;}
.chromestyle {display: inline-block; width: auto;}
.chromestyle > table {width: auto;} /* remove width attribute! */
.chromestyle > table ul {width: auto;}
```

Comment: Hm no dice. Yeah I didn't design this website I'm just the guy they hired to update it :P

Comment: Things seem to be changing as I look. Is there a JavaScript plugin setting widths?

Comment: Hm I wonder why the corners of the menu table don't match the front page.

Comment: Yeah, you might need to fiddle a bit further.